# "You don't have permission..." uninstalling xcode on Catalina

Tags: catalina, xcode, macos

I installed xcode long before my Catalina upgrade. I currently don't need the bloat on my mac and was going to try to remove it. However, I'm getting "You don't have permission to perform this task" when I try to move it to the trash. I am an administrator locally. Appreciate any help.

```
$ ls -la  /Applications | grep Xcode
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root wheel 96 Apr 17 09:03 Xcode.app
```

Comment: Open about this Mac app > storage > manage > applications > click on Xcode > remove.

Comment: thanks @ankii, however when I click Delete... in System Info applications list, it prompts "Are you sure you want o delete "XCode"?. When I click Delete it still remains.

Comment: which folder are you trying to remove Xcode from ? I'm on Mojave but I read that Catalina has two places for applications. Also what is the output of `ls -la | grep Xcode
` ? I was hesitant sugesting `rm` to remove it, but maybe it's necessary, & after some failures, with sudo too.

Comment: /Applications `drwxr-xr-x@  3 root        wheel          96 Apr 17 09:03 Xcode.app`

Comment: Try ```sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app``` and then removing ```Xcode.app``` if necessary.

Comment: Yup `sudo rm -fr` usually works pretty well 

Comment: Yeah, #bighammer :)